# What is the meaning of "Projection is relevant only in Hilbert Space"? Why it is non relevant in non-Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection

I am reading ergodic theory notes. While reading about the mean ergodic theorem of von Neuman, I was perplexed by the following statement:

> " In the $L^2$ case it was projection onto a certain subspace, but since
> $L^1$ is not a Hilbert space, we can’t make sense of “projection
> operators” as we did before"

Why are projection operators relevant only in a Hilbert space? And is there an example for why those kind of operators are not relevant in non-Hilbert spaces? ($L^{1}$ for example)?

(Here are the notes I follow [https://www.mit.edu/~fengt/ergodic_theory.pdf](https://www.mit.edu/%7Efengt/ergodic_theory.pdf))

Comment: Orthogonal projection is defined by orthogonality, which is defined using the inner product.

Comment: But don't we have the same inner product  defined in $L^{1}$ also?

Comment: It seems like the term "projection" is implicitly used as "orthogonal projection" in the linked notes, which I would say is technically wrong. Then it really makes sense to have "[orthogonal] projection" only in a space with inner product. Projections and projection operators makes sense in many contexts different from Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Using a different naming convention isn't "technically wrong" @Korf especially when the convention is a common one.

Comment: The $L^2$ inner product is not well-defined on $L^1$ as the integral needn't converge.

Comment: Perhaps it is helpful to note the following general fact: A Banach space is isomorphic to a Hilbert space iff every closed subspace is complemented.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because Hilbert's projection theorem is true only in Hilbert spaces! And he probably needs that. If $H$ is a subspace of $X$ (Hilbert) and $x$ not in $H$ then there is a unique element $m$ of $H$ such that $min_{H}$$\left\|y-x \right\|=\left\|m-x \right\|$ and $<m-x,y>=0$ for all $y$ in $H$. So projection, orthogonality and inner product are a family of properties only met in Hilbert spaces!!